# Can someone explain reddit's created_utc and how to convert it into a usable format in php

Tags: php, reddit

Im looking at http://www.reddit.com/user/MrLuxan/about.json and it gives the created_utc as 1304465246.0 but not sure how it match up with anything on [PHP:date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Can anyone explain it to me and give how I can turn it into a usable format

Comment: You should be able to just put that timestamp into the date function like `date("m/d/Y", $timestamp);` It would be helpful to see your code though to get a better understanding of what you are trying to display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be a [UNIX-timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and you can convert it to something human-readable by doing the following:

```
$timestamp = 1304465246;

echo date('m/d/Y', $timestamp);
```

and you will get `05/04/2011` back.

Have a look at [PHP: date](http://php.net/date) for on how you can format it to your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

It's a unix timestamp. Convert it using the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object:

```
$dt = new DateTime('@'.'1313790243');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // output: 2011-08-19 21:44:03
```

You can also use the [DateTimeZone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) object to convert it to your timezone (or whichever timezone you prefer):

```
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // output: 2011-08-19 17:44:03
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please keep timezones in mind. They are important in displaying the correct local time for your site/users.